# Unable to 'make prod' Akeneo PIM on macOS Catalina using Docker

Tags: macos, makefile, akeneo

I am trying to install Akeneo PIM Community Edition on my macOS Catalina following these instructions: https://docs.akeneo.com/4.0/install_pim/docker/installation_docker.html

Steps using Docker are successful until I want to launch PIM in prod mode using the command

`$ make prod`

when I get the error message: *make: *** No rule to make target `prod'.  Stop.*

I execute this command inside the 'pim' directory in my home directory (~iwan/pim).

Instructions say the make command needs to be executed within directory /srv/pim but I do not find this directory on my Mac.

Where do I find /srv/pim or what went wrong?

Thanks for any help,
Iwan

in directory ~iwan/pim (pim is a subdirectory in my home directory (iwan))

Answer (score 0):

The `/srv/pim` directory exists inside the `pim_fpm_1` container and is mapped via a volume to your `~/iwan/pim` directory.
There should be a Makefile in this directory with lines like these:

```
.PHONY: prod
prod:
  $(MAKE) dependencies
  $(MAKE) pim-prod
```

(The Makefile was created when you ran the commands under https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/install_pim/docker/installation_docker.html#creating-the-pim-project)